# Angularjs iterate through multiple json arrays

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm quite new to Angularjs, and I'm doing an $http.get from a json. I've gotten the response and it works. The only problem is that I have to hard-code the handlebars rather than do a ng-repeat

```
{{country.results[0]["breakfast/_text"][1] }}
{{country.results[0]["breakfast/_text"][2] }}
{{country.results[0]["breakfast/_text"][3] }}
{{country.results[1]["breakfast/_text"][1] }}
{{country.results[1]["breakfast/_text"][2] }}
{country.results[1]["breakfast/_text"][3] }} 
{{country.results[1]["breakfast/_text"][4] }}
{{country.results[2]["breakfast/_text"][1] }}
{country.results[2]["breakfast/_text"][2] }} 
{{country.results[2]["breakfast/_text"][3] }} 
{{country.results[3]["breakfast/_text"][1] }} 
{{country.results[3]["breakfast/_text"][2] }}
```

How do I do an ng-repeat for a 2-d json array like this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use two nested `ngRepeat` directives. This should render it:

```
<div ng-repeat="result in country.results">
    <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in result['breakfast/_text']">
        {{value}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried directly copying and pasting it and it didn't work. Must I make any changes to the angularjs portion? Shouldn't there be another ng-repeat for each iteration in result?

Comment: Can you post the structure of `country` object?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AbS2oyQuBKet6bIHcfQR) and use ng-repeat for 2D data like this.

```
$scope.data = [
  {'text':[1,2,3]},
  {'text':[3,4,5]},
  {'text':[5,6,7]},
  ];
```

and

```
<div ng-repeat="result in data">
       <div ng-repeat="value in result">
        <div ng-repeat="values in value">
        {{values}}
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

This might help you .